Excel - Is it possible to apply formulas directly to linked CSV values?
A spreadsheet is linked to a CSV file with headers.
Some columns in the spreadsheet should be divided by certain amounts so that displayed values become meaningful.
e.g. All linked values in a column to display divided by 10.
Is there a way to achieve that?

Depends how complicated or efficient you need it to be. You could use formulas in separate columns to display adjusted values, and hide the original ones. Or you could put those formulas into the query editor as TransformColumn steps
